# R: Aggregate with ddply Produce Odd Date Format

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr

I have a data frame like so:

```
> df
Keyword  Date    Pos  Bid
a       1/14/14   1    5
a       1/15/14   1    5
a       1/16/14   1    5
b        2/4/14   5    9
b        2/5/14   2    9
b        2/5/14   2    9
c       3/21/14   3    5
c       3/23/14   1    9
c       3/23/14   2    10
```

I was able to filter so that I get the latest observation with this:

```
Late = ddply(df, 'Keyword', function(x) {Date = as.Date(x$Date, '%m/%d/%y') 
                                         x[Date == max(Date), 
                                         c('Keyword', 'Date', 'Pos', 'Bid')]})

> Late
Keyword  Date    Pos  Bid
a       1/16/14   1    5
b        2/5/14   2    9
b        2/5/14   2    9
c       3/23/14   1    9
c       3/23/14   2    10
```

Now, I to have unique Keywords, unique Dates, min Pos, and max Bid:

```
WANT THIS:

> Late
Keyword  Date    Pos  Bid
a       1/16/14   1    5
b        2/5/14   2    9
c       3/23/14   1    10
```

so I did another ddply:

```
Late = ddply(Late, .(Keyword, Date), function(x) c(Keyword = unique(x$Keyword), 
                                                   Date = unique(as.Date(x$Date, '%m/%d/%y')), 
                                                   Pos = min(x$Pos), 
                                                   Bid = max(x$Bid)))
```

But this gave me rubbish for Date:

```
> Late
Keyword  Date    Pos  Bid
a       16086     1    5
b       16086     2    9
c       16088     1    10
```

I have tried various code for Date, but they do not work.  What am I missing?

Thanks.

Comment: Because it is a different question.  This has to do with Date in an unusable format.

Comment: And I did use one of them, but I should have elaborated more on my question.  Thanks for understanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
ddply(df, .(Keyword), function(x) c(Date = as.character(x$Date[which.max(as.Date(x$Date, '%m/%d/%y'))]), 
                                    Pos = min(x$Pos), 
                                    Bid = max(x$Bid)))

##   Keyword    Date Pos Bid
## 1       a 1/16/14   1   5
## 2       b  2/5/14   2   9
## 3       c 3/23/14   1  10
```

Comment: Thanks for still answering despite it being a different yet related question.